# How to run BIND DNS server as unpriviledged user?

Tags: networking, server, dns

I am developer and I use `BIND` `DNS` server to debug software. On Windows and on CentOS 6 Linux it is not a problem. I use following command line:

`named -f -c "/my/custom/config.conf"`

It works OK (of course, I allow port 53 in firewall settings).
However, with Ubuntu 14 `BIND` fails silently when I try to run the same command. There are not log file records that allow to supposed what is problem. I also tried to run this command with `sudo`, however, it doesn't change anything.
What may be silent failure reason and how to run `BIND` as unpriviledged process with custom configuration file on Ubuntu?